# Excel - Search through a column to find if text matches and count string

Tags: excel, formula, worksheet

I want to add values from 1 worksheet to another.

The first worksheet ("November 2011") simply contains name & status, names are however duplicated and a percentage of a string needs to be added on the second worksheet ("Sales").

e.g. "November 2011"

```
    A           B
1   Name        Status
2   McDonalds   Completed
3   McDonalds   Won
4   Burger King Won
5   Burger King Won
6   Wendys      Completed
7   iHop        Completed
8   iHop        Completed
```

The second worksheet ("Sales") contains 3 columns Name, Completed & Won. However, Name has had duplicates removed.

e.g. "Sales"

```
    A           B           C
1   Name        Completed   Won
2   McDonalds   
3   Burger King 
4   Wendys      
5   iHop
```

I want the "Sales" worksheet to look like this however:

```
    A           B           C
1   Name        Completed   Won
2   McDonalds   50%         50%
3   Burger King 0%          100%
4   Wendys      100%        0%
5   iHop        100%        0%
```

Just wondering what formula to use? It needs to check against the name.

Comment: unable to, unfortunately

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a [`countif`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) function to find the number of sales and [`countifs`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) to find the number of wins and completed.

```
=COUNTIFS('November 2011'!$A:$A, A2, 'November 2011'!$B:$B, "won") 
  / COUNTIF('November 2011'!$A:$A,A2)
```

This would give you the ratio or percent if formatted of the **won**.

Comment: The syntax may be out I can't test as I'm on my phone. There are some links in my answer.

Comment: =COUNTIFS('November 2011'!$A:$A, A2, 'November 2011'!$B:$B, "won") /  COUNTIF('November 2011'!$A:$A,A2)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use an "array formula" with AVERAGE function, i.e. this formula in B2

`=AVERAGE(IF(November 2011'!$A$2:$A$1000=$A2,IF('November 2011'!$B$2:$B$1000=B$1,1,0)))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copied across and down

Comment: This answer is definitely needed for pre-2007 Excel. Weldone.